# Got the python version wrong when deploy my flask app to heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

When I deploy my flask app to heroku,I got the error :The lastest version of python 3 is python-3.6.3(you are using Python-2.7.13,which is unsupported).

My virtualenv is python3.5.3,and runtime.txt:python 3.5.3,and my app include the requirements.txt and Procfile ,it's no wrong when I run:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

,but When I run:

```
git push heroku master
```

I got:

```
.....
--->Python app detected

The lastest version of python 3 is python-3.6.3(you are using Python-2.7.13,which is unsupported).
We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version(python-3.6.3).
Learn more:https//devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
--->Installing Python-2.7.13

Requested runtime (Python-2.7.13) is not available for this stack(heroku-16).
Aborting. More info:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support.
Push failed
....
.....
```

when I performed `$:python -V`,it's **python3.5.3**, I dont know what is wrong with my app,I install all my packages in the **python3.5.3** virtualenv,and I have try to change the runtime.txt:python 3.6.3,it's not work.I am new to python and flask web,thank you for your answer.

And my project structure as the picture shows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7hCe.png)

I checked my heroku logs,but it's sad for me that I dont know what does it mean:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGpFQ.png)

Comment: are you sure your runtime.txt is under version control?

Comment: Yes,I run all my files by:git add . and git commit -m "ver1.0"...

Comment: can you please your project folder structure, are you sure the runtime.txt is in root folder of the project?

Comment: Yes,I edit my question by adding the picture of my project structure,and the runtime.txt is indeed  in root folder of the project

Comment: i saw everything you added but it  sound like heroku doesn't read the runtime.txt

Comment: em,it's too strange,although I have deployed the app for several times...

Comment: I know what's wrong ,since you said that  heroku doesn't read my runtime.txt,and then I try to install python 3.6.3 in virtualenv,but failed,it turned out that my ubuntu system was broken,due to long time to find the cause,I reinstall the system,install 3.6.3,and no problems happened on the way on heroku.thank you so much..